# Why is get_long_long("") printing 2 times?

Tags: c, cs50

`get_long_long("")` from the code below is printing 2 times and I'm not sure why. It prints, `Please enter your credit card number..."`, 2 times. (Note: I'm not scamming people, we are doing this project for AP computer science class, basically writing a program that checks to see if the card is legit.)

This isn't the full code, just the beginning which asks which card provider they have and then will use that info to determine if the card is legit.

```
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>


    char type1[100]; //array used to store and then compare which card is being used
    char visa[25] = "Visa";
    char amex[25] = "Amex";
    char master[25] = "Mastercard";
    long long card;

    int main(void)
    {
        printf("Is your card Visa, Mastercard, or Amex?\n");
        //read the card type then store it in type array
        scanf("%s", type1);


        if (strcmp(type1, master) == 0 || strcmp(type1, visa) == 0 || 
        strcmp(type1, amex) == 0)
        {
            card = get_long_long("Please enter your credit card 
            number\n");
        }
        do
        {
            printf("Is your card Visa, Mastercard, or Amex?\n");
            scanf("%s", type1);
        }
        while (strcmp(type1, master) == 0 || strcmp(type1, visa) == 0 
            || strcmp(type1, amex) != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` conversion `%s` matches a sequence of *non-white-space* characters (after skipping any leading white-space) and stops upon encountering trailing white-space. This means that any trailing white-space, such as the newline at the end of the line, is left unread. Even without knowing the internals of the non-standard `get_long_long`, I am almost certain that it first encounters the newline and asks again since that looks identical to the user just pressing enter without typing anything else.

Comment: thank you. Is there any advice you have for a beginner like me to be able to fix this?

Comment: Detail: The scanf conversion %s matches a sequence of 1) optional leading whites spaces (which are not saved), then 2) non-white-space characters (saved) and 3) stops upon encountering whitespace (un-gotten).  Answer skips #1 part.

Comment: @MikeFerraro In general, you will have fewer problems by reading with `fgets` into a buffer and parsing that, than reading input directly with `scanf`.

Comment: (And, yes, @chux is correct that leading whitespace is skipped, as with most `scanf` conversions.)